# zsh: command not found: adb in mac OS

Tags: android, adb, zsh

I am getting `zsh: command not found: adb` error even after updating my `.zshrc` file.
I have added the following path in my `.zshrc` file

```
# For ADB
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

`declare -p PATH` is returning the following path

```
export -T PATH path=( /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools /Users/aanshu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin )
```

Comment: Where is your actual `adb` executable? If you run `declare -p PATH`, does it reflect this configuration, showing the extra entries it's intended to add?

Comment: I did not understand are you talking about path ?

Comment: The PATH is the variable you're setting to tell the shell where to look for executables. If you run `echo "$PATH"` or `declare -p PATH` it will show the actual value.

Comment: If your edited file was never invoked, then showing the `PATH` won't show the changes you made. We need to know if that's the case.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're pointing `ANDROID_HOME` at the wrong place. It shouldn't point all the way to the `adb` executable; it should point to the `.../Library/Android/sdk` directory.

Comment: `export -T PATH path=( /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools /Users/aanshu/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools/bin /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/tools `

Comment: `/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin )`

Comment: Thank you for the above (but for the future, such content should be [edit]ed into the question instead of just added as comments). The other thing: What's the output of `find /Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk -name adb -type f -print`?

Comment: ...basically, once you have the `find` output, you need to make sure that the directory containing the `adb` executable (not the executable itself, but its parent directory) is one of the things shown in the dumped `PATH` list.

Comment: ...I suspect that the _real_ location of the executable is `/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`; but instead of adding `/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` to the PATH, you're instead adding `/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb/platform-tools`

Comment: yes that was the issue @CharlesDuffy I was adding the incorrect path

Comment: Why would you edit a **bash** config file if you're using **zsh**?

Comment: @Shawn sorry i mean `.zshrc` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

...is obviously wrong. It should instead be:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/aanshu/Library/Android/sdk
```

...because it provides a base to which the subsequent lines append.

Comment: @qkx, the code in your comment above is overriding PATH, not appending to it. Nothing at all in this answer tells you to do that, so I don't know why you're blaming me.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to answer this this lately ..
For me these are the things that I did.

- •    Copy the platform-tools to the user home folder
- •    Then opened terminal and entered “ nano .zshrc ”
- •    In that text editor I added the below line

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/user_name/android-sdk-macos/platform-tools/

- then save it user control+x and exit the text editor
- •    In the terminal I entered “ source  ~/.zshrc “
- •    Closed all terminals and reponed it.

  That’s it

Then  I tried adb devices in the terminal to test if it works or not. and It was working

Comment: "In that text editor I added the below line - o export" what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @BorisGafurov sorry brother..

the command was like this..
" 
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/user_name/android-sdk-macos/platform-tools/ "


forgot to add newline after " - o"